# How to get Borough names using ArcGIS API for Python through geocoding?

Tags: geocoding, arcgis-python-api

I'm new to ArcGIS API for Python. Is it possible to do do geocoding of an area, specifically New York City and get all the boroughs' names?

i.e.: Geocode request for all boroughs in New York city.

```
in[x]: geocoding.geocode('New York, NY')
out[x]:{'address': 'New York',
'location': {'x': -74.00713999999994, 'y': 40.71455000000003},
 'score': 100,
 'attributes': {'Loc_name': 'World',
  'Status': 'T',
  'Score': 100,
  'Match_addr': 'New York',
  'LongLabel': 'New York, NY, USA',
  'ShortLabel': 'New York',
  'Addr_type': 'Locality',
  'Type': 'City',
  'PlaceName': 'New York',
  'Place_addr': 'New York',
  'Rank': 2.5,
  'AddBldg': '',
  'Nbrhd': '',
  'District': '',
  'City': 'New York',
  'MetroArea': 'New York City Metro',
  'Subregion': 'New York County',
  'Region': 'New York',
  'RegionAbbr': 'NY',
  'Territory': '',
  'Country': 'USA',
  'LangCode': 'ENG',
  'Distance': 0,'},
 'extent': {'xmin': -74.25713999999994,
  'ymin': 40.46455000000003,
  'xmax': -73.75713999999994,
  'ymax': 40.96455000000003}}
```

and get  in the 'District' element: 'Bronx, Brooklyn, Manhattan, Queens, Staten Island'

Comment: Maybe? Do you already have a reference to a layer of New York city with this information inside? The Python API is designed to work against Enterprise or Online and the services inside. You'd typically need to find this data before you can conduct a query.

Comment: KHibma, I do not have a layer with this data. I've been trying to do this query using ArcGIs.geocoding libary. I just want to query the information that ArcGis already have in their database. 
i.e.:

[in]: geocoding.geocode('New York',max_locations=1)
[out]: [{'address': 'New York',
  'location': {'x': -74.00713999999994, 'y': 40.71455000000003},
  'attributes': {'Loc_name': 'World',
   'Sector': '',
   'Nbrhd': '',
   'District': '',
...}}
And get in the 'District' element the name of all the districs in NY city.

Comment: I'll update your question/tags to reflect that.

Comment: Simply as a starter, my guess is you need to set a category. However, in a few quick attempts I don't get any responses limited to just the boroughs. Reference: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-category-filtering.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please [edit] your question to include your code attempts (rather than putting code snippets in comments) to show what you have tried and where you are having trouble. And as a new user, please be sure to take the site [tour]!

Comment: @Andy this question isn't so much "how do I code", as it is "will the esri world geocoder provided the result I want"

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to get the Districs' names somehow. Maybe geocoding.geocode libary it is not the best way to achive my goal.  If someone knows how to get this kind of information, and have another method, I'll be thankful.